# Why is Claire not in the ending with Alice?

Tags: ending, resident-evil, resident-evil-the-final-chapter

*Resident Evil: The Final Chapter* ends with Alice releasing the anti-virus into the atmosphere and it will take several years for the Antivirus to spread in the Whole World, As she turns the Red queen back online with Claire, She gains Alicia's memory through an Upload.

Alice, Claire, and the Red queen is seen having a conversation with the Red Queen

[image]

After that, The last moment of Alice driving an Umbrella Motorcycle on her own.

[image]

[image]

The question is, Why is Claire not with her? what happened to her? Why she did not come with Alice while Driving?

The director Anderson doesn't say anything about that one. But how about you guys? Any answers or Opinions?

Comment: If you noticed something that i forgot to add, Please humbly ask me about that and i will add it in my Info. Thank you and have a Nice Day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my interpretations, showing Alice in the closing scene is more of giving the franchise a full circle end. If you remember in the first *Resident Evil* after the prologue, Alice is the one we got introduced to first and she is the one who is closing the franchise with her last mission to not rest until she kills each monster.

It's a full circle now. Showing Claire in the last scene adds no cinematic advantage (maybe tactical advantage in the fight). But then from the movie itself, we don't know what Claire was doing after the memory transplant scene so the max we can do is assume. Maybe Claire is leading the survivors to safe haven or maybe fighting zombies off screen.

Comment: Thanks Bro! i hope claire is safe even if she is not in the Ending scene. 

Wait Claire Fighting zombies offscreen? But Alice released the Anti virus in the atmosphere right? all the undead were killed by it. Who knows about that?

Comment: Alice said herself in end antivirus will take years to spread so she is still taking care of as many zombies she can till then.

Comment: i fully understand now and thanks a lot! , i hope the survivors offscreen weren't harmed by any monsters as well claire, and i hope alice can rest with peace with her Daughter becky.

Comment: Now the franchise is rebooted with new actors playing Claire , Chris , Jill etc

Comment: i have also seen that one, It's also great but the Characters we're only changed at some point like Jill and leon but they did better on Chris, claire and William birkin. Lily gao as ada wong is ok but i prefer Li bingbing in the Retritubion. it's awesome scene as well the train fight